# Extract Value from Column A and then get the count for certain values from Column B for the value in Column A

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

The table structure that I have right now is as below:

```
Column A  Column B          

Apple     1
Apple     2 
Apple     1
Orange    1
Orange    2
```

I am trying to write a formula where, for all the cells with the value of Apple in column A, I get the total count for values in column B equal to 1.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you are just after the formula

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"Apple",B:B,1)
```

Comment: Thank you. If the same data in column B was replaced by dates, and I wanted a counted of all dates before 8/25/2017, how would I do that?

Comment: @Ankit `=COUNTIFS(A:A,"Apple",B:B,"<"&DATE(2016,8,25))`